# jQuery UI droppable problem

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a script that uses jQuery UI's graggable and droppable functionality.

Items are dragged from left panel into main area and dropped.

There are two scenarios:

1. Items are dropped into other boxes, preset on page load or can be dropped into main area to create a new box. The items can be moved between the boxes. Everything works fine with this setup.
2. In second scenario there are no preset boxes in main area. They are supposed to be created whn an item is dragged and dropped from the left panel. However, for some reason it only allows me to create one box. Here's an [example](http://www.c8r.us/uxxzhmb).

My level of UI proficiency is not high enough to spot what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in this code:

```
$.when(createEmptyStack()).then(function(data) { ... }
```

`data` is always `""` meaning that you're attempting to add a new element to the page with the same `id` over and over again (your AJAX request to `createEmptyStack` is not returning anything in the response). This is why it works fine the first time; the `id` doesn't exist and so the code works as expected.

When you drag another item into the main area, the element *may* be successfully appended, but it has a duplicate `id`. This code:

```
putCardIntoStack(ui.draggable,newstackId);
```

(in the same block as the code above)

Is always called with the draggable object and just `STACK` as the `newstackId`.

In short, this is a problem with your server-side code not returning a stack id. According to Firebug, your AJAX request isn't returning anything at all.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I added some code earlier today and it blocked my PHP script from getting the new ID. I fixed that and noticed another problem: I can create new boxes by dropping items but I can't seem to be able to move items between the boxes...

Comment: I think I got it! Part of the same problem -- I was using an creator ID. Not that it's fixed, how do I make my draggable items to be always on top? I even tried adding z-index:9999, but the stacks seem to be always above... weird.

Comment: @santa: Have you tried playing with the `stack` option? http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-stack

Comment: Yes, I have that added but it seems the other elements still manage to have it higher.